# CSS span text overlay over image issue

Tags: html, css

I've uploaded an image, but I can't get the date box to positioned correctly. As you can see, there's also a date box all the way to the right. I think a lot of the issue is due to `position: absolute`, but it would be nice if there's a way to make it stay in the div. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the code.

```
.event-picture-block { display: inline;}
.event-date-box { position: absolute; margin-top: 300px; margin-left: 2.4%; background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 35px; width: 10%; text-align: center; }
.event-image { width: 33.1%; }

<div class="container">
<% @events.each do |event| %>
<div class="event-picture-block">
  <span class="event-date-box">
    <%= event.date.strftime("%^b %e") %>
  </span>
  <%= link_to event_path(event), class:"link-margin" do %>
    <%= image_tag(event.image.url(:small), :class =>"event-image") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please paste some code or make a jsfiddle

Comment: An image of your code and the output is almost worthless. Please copy+paste the relevant code in to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately we won't be able to help you with an image alone. Please post your HTML and CSS snippets as well.

Comment: JSFiddle, but don't know how to make it work with Ruby.

https://jsfiddle.net/w3yaw975/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add position: relative to picture-block:

```
.event-picture-block { display: inline;position:relative;}
```

And change rest css property as per your requirements.

Comment: I did that, but the date text box still goes off screen on the top row. EDIT: Turns out I have a margin-right:-3px; Thanks. I might have to delete due to my downvotes.